# Textbooks with worked examples on identifiability and regularity

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

I'm looking for textbooks that would have worked examples on identifiability and regularity, something similar to a Schaum's outline.

Are there any textbooks that have worked examples on these topics?

I am currently using Bickel and Doksum but it is quite difficult.